# Displaying PDF document in a Java(SE) Standalone Application

Tags: java, swing

Am working on a Java application that requires me to display PDF documents within the application. Am not sure if Java currently supports this or will i need to get a Java library to get this done.

Please, i need advise on how to go about this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://today.java.net/article/2005/10/18/accessing-pdf-document-acrobat-viewer-javabean

Comment: There is a library found [here](http://itextpdf.com/) that will do exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: iText does not have support for displaying PDF documents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [pdf-renderer](https://pdf-renderer.dev.java.net/)

> The PDF Renderer is just what the name implies: an open source, all Java library which renders PDF documents to the screen using Java2D.